# How can I add the logged in user's name in form django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I just want to put the username of the logged in user inside the author field and at the same time assign the author field as the user's username in the database.

```
def create_vacation(request):
    form = creationForm(request.POST or None)
    vacations = Vacation.objects.all()
    vacations.author=request.user.username
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return redirect('/vacations/all')

    return render(request, 'creationForm.html', {'form': form})
```

and this is the vacation model

```
class Vacation(models.Model):
    vacationInformation = models.TextField()
    startDate= models.DateTimeField('start date')
    endDate = models.DateTimeField('end date')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self. vacationInformation
```

this is the form template

```
 <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden_field }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ field.label_tag }}

            {% if form.is_bound %}
            {% if field.errors %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                {{ error }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
            {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if field.help_text %}
            <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
            {% if vacation %}

        {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

I can render all of the vacation data in the homepage normally except for sure the author name

```
 {% for vacation in vacations %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ vacation.vacationInformation }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacation.startDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacation.endDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacation.author }}</td>
```

It is giving me the entire user names in the author field in the form but I just want the user whom is logged in.

Comment: Where is the definition of `creationForm`? (e.g. `class creationForm(forms.Form): ...`).

Comment: class creationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vacation
        fields = ['vacationInformation', 'startDate', 'endDate' , 'author' ]

Comment: i dont know if this helps but i logged the objects and especially the author it gave me this , since author is an object

Comment: Vacation.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\aiiaProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 255, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\aiiaProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 518, in __repr__
    return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type User)

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the currently logged in User. Then you can use the User to fill in the initial values in the form.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user
# ...

def create_vacation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = creationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/vacations/all')
    else:
        # Get the currently logged-in User.
        user = get_user(request)
        # Provide User as initial data to the form
        form = creationForm(initial={'author': user})

    return render(request, 'creationForm.html', {'form': form})
```

Relevant documentation:

- [ModelForm - Providing initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)
- [django.contrib.auth.get_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.get_user)